# Dates in Drupal are off by one day when logged in

Tags: date, drupal-6

Dates on a website I maintain display fine, until I log in (as an admin). Then they are off by minus one day.
I figured this is because the timestamps are then displayed in UTC while they should be displayed in UTC+1. And since UTC is one hour off, days display one day off.
I could hunt down every piece of code displaying dates and hard code them to always display as UTC+1 (which is what I want), but I have a feeling there might be an easier, global way to fix this.

Comment: A quick solution was to disable "User-configurable time zones" in the Date and time settings. (http://drupal.org/node/15369)
I still don't know if there is a way to set a default time zone for the users, would I not want to disable this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your timezone settings. Drupal must be using it for displaying dates.